# How do I disable the vertical scroll roller for?

Tags: css, disabled-control

I set my homepage this **css** property, but this not enough:

```
body {
overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

Because when you press the roller on your mouse, you can scroll to the right side and left side.
So how can I disable this?

Comment: `html,body{overflow:hidden;}` doesn't work ?

Comment: Sorry I miss one attribute

Answer (score 0):

is possibly because the elements of your page has a greater height than the page itself, there even if you hide the scroll bar on the User may scroll the page with the mouse or by selecting and dragging on your page.
then I ask you to look at the size of the elements of your page and visible station

Comment: I don't know what element not responsive, becouse my wordpress tamplate very responsive.
I saw my page differend resolution,but I not have any result